# Hijacking system("/bin/sh") to run arbitrary commands

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm trying to perform a privilege escalation attack using a binary which performs the call:

```
system("/bin/sh");
```

Is there a way to pass commands as "arguments" or such with the opened shell?
(I don't see it opening, I guess it runs and dies as soon as it has nothing to do which is immediately).

Edit: I **Cannot** edit the code. It's compiled already.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can just append any arguments you want to pass to the `/bin/sh` to the string passed to `system`. That is, to pass an argument `foo` to `bin/sh`, you'd do `system("/bin/sh foo")`. BTW, you're question is a little hard to understand, so I suggest you make it very clear what your actual problem is and omit any unnecessary information.

Comment: `system("/bin/sh")` is really nonsensical code, btw. It runs `/bin/sh -c /bin/sh`, since `system()` calls `/bin/sh -c` with whatever argument it's given.

Comment: BTW, in general this might be more of a question for [Infosec SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: BTW, how exactly is the command escalating its privileges? `sudo`, the setuid bit, etc. all have their own security measures.

Comment: (BTW, the folks writing this program violated one of the rules given in https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Tips-for-Setuid.html -- "You should never use system in a privileged program, because it invokes a shell.")

Answer (score 1):

If you execute

```
system("/bin/bash");
```

the shell enters into interactive mode. It reads commands from standard input and writes answers to standard output. The standard input and output is inherited from the calling (your) program. Your program will wait until the shell finishes (i.e. until you enter the command `exit` or you type ^D at the beginning of line). The shell will run with the same privileges as the calling program.

Comment: If the OP had an interactive TTY (and it were passed through on stdin), then the shell wouldn't be "immediately" exiting as they describe.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you control stdin

What you'll need to do is connect stdin to something that will, when read, provide a source of commands **before** invoking that code.

I'm writing the below in bash, but you can convert it to whatever language you actually intend to do this in:

```
# create a file with the commands you want to run
cat >/tmp/commands <<'EOF'
echo "Hello world"
EOF

# open that file and copy its file descriptor to FD 0 (stdin)
exec </tmp/commands

# then invoke your compiled executable that starts a shell.
run-your-command-that-starts-a-shell
```

---

#### If the program controls or overrides its stdin

Another option is to pass `ENV` with the name of a file to source:

```
cat >/tmp/commands <<'EOF'
echo "Hello world"
EOF
ENV=/tmp/commands run-your-command-that-starts-a-shell
```